# Class variables with params values in ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In appllication controller i have couple of methods that works with requested controller and action name.

To follow DRY principe, i want to define share variables with those params.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   @@requested_action     = params[:action]
   @@requested_controller = params[:controller]
end
```

But i get error: `undefined local variable or method "params" for ApplicationController:Class`

Why i can't do this and how can i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you already have `controller_name` and `action_name` variables defined by Rails for this purpose.

If you want to do it by your way, you must define it as a before filter as params comes to existence only after the request is made. You can do something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_action_and_controller

  def set_action_and_controller
    @controller_name = params[:controller]
    @action_name = params[:action]
  end
end
```

You can access them as @controller_name and @action_name. But `controller_name` and `action_name` are already defined in Rails. You can use them directly.

Comment: Thanks for this. Testing with Rails 4.2.1, in the ApplicationController but outside of a before_filter, controller_name is "application"; action_name and params don't exist. Inside a before_filter, controller_name corresponds to the controller that is being loaded and the other two are also set. So the comment about params not coming into existence until the request is made is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

Use instance methods instead:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def requested_action
    params[:action] if params
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use before_filter option.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_share_variable

  protected

  def set_share_variable
    @requested_action     = params[:action]
    @requested_controller = params[:controller]
  end
end
```